# Code in viewDidLoad runs every time it is called

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Hi all I am doing a course in Udemy, and the code calls for placing code in the viewDidLoad function as shown below:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    placesArray.append(["name":"Taj Mahal", "lat":"27.175607", "lon":"78.042112"])

}
```

The array append should only run once, however, when I segue to another viewController and come back, it runs the code to append again. So I now have an array with 2 rows, both of which are Taj Mahal.

I thought that the viewDidLoad function only runs code once?

Is there a way around this?

Thanks.

Addendum:
I am using Swift, so I don't see any alloc and init while creating and launching the viewController. And weird as it sounds, the video tutorial has it working in the viewDidLoad and the trainer is using the storyboard to segue from the initial table view controller to a map view on a view controller and just has a back button on the map view that segue's back to the table view controller via the storyboard as well. - Could be because I have the latest version of the Swift language and the trainer was using an earlier version, (cause I noticed some slight differences in coding earlier) but you never know. Either way whenever he touches the back button it does not run the append code anymore.
I am trying to get in contact with the trainer as some of the suggestions here, though they are good don't seem to work.
I will put the solution in here once I get in contact with the trainer.

Comment: Maybe when u segue to the other viewController the old one is dealloc, and when u came back it's loads again?!

Comment: You're probably coming back with a segue that's not an unwind. You should not do that. It creates a new instance, it doesn't actually come back.

Answer (score 1):

The `viewDidLoad` method is called when your view controller's `view` finishes loading. The `view` will load when a view controller's `view` property is `nil` and something attempts to access it.

```
UIViewController *myVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIView *aView = myVC.view; // this loads myVC's view; viewDidLoad is called when it completes loading.
```

If the `view` has unloaded (usually due to memory limitations), it will be called when the `view` property is next accessed.

Manipulation of data sets should generally not be done within view methods. Consider moving this to the `init` of the view controller (or to a different "datasource" class).

Comment: More specifically. viewDidLoad gets called whenever the view controller view's frame is invoked. So for example, if you set it's frame size to the container's size then viewDidLoad will get hit. But viewWillAppear & viewDidAppear won't get hit until after addSubview (or a variant)

Comment: @GnarlyDog: No, this is untrue. Calling `self.view.frame = someFrame` does not cause `viewDidLoad` if your `view` property is already set. For example, `self.view.frame` is set when you rotate your screen, but you do not get a `viewDidLoad` call on each rotation unless you have nuked your `view`.

Comment: Sorry for the vague response. I specifically meant after you alloc init, not every time you set the frame. I just alloc inited a ViewController inside another, but didn't present it or add it's subview to a view. viewDidLoad was not called. However if I set view.frame = my.view.frame then viewDidLoad was called. BUT viewWillAppear was not. Essentially, viewDidLoad (and loadView) seems to be called lazily.

Comment: Yes. The accession of `self.view` is what causes the `viewDidLoad`, not the `.frame`. For clarity, I've updated the example.

Comment: Views don't get unloaded any more, memory pressure or not. `viewDidLoad` will be called once in the lifecycle of any view controller unless you, the developer, nil out the view, which is a bad idea

Comment: Otherwise, your answer is spot on, but rdelmar's comment is probably the real right answer

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad` is called whenever the view controller's view property is set. When does this happen? It depends on how the view controller is contained:

UINavigationController
- View Controller views are loaded as they are added to the navigation stack and "unloaded" (although the `viewDidUnload` method is deprecated) as they are removed.

UITabBarController
- View Controller views are loaded as they are added to the tab bar regardless of whether they are on screen or not. They stay loaded as you change from tab to tab.

Depending on your needs and use case, you can create your own view controller container that does what you need. Checkout the Apple docs on the proper way to do this:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are trying to do data initialisation in viewDidLoad. If there is no other operation on placesArray before viewDidLoad, then instead of append, what about setting the placesArray directly:

```
placesArray = ["name":"Taj Mahal", "lat":"27.175607", "lon":"78.042112"]
```

Then even if your view is unloaded for some reasons. Taj Mahal will still be added once only.